# jasmine test complaining with undefined is not an object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I use AngularJs and i need to test element of my init with Jasmine like this :

```
var init = function () {
    _this.tenant = tenant.data;

    _this.types = [
      { value: "true", label: "Tenant" },
      { value: "false", label: "Project" }
    ];

    //Pre-select the good type
    var index;
    _.each(_this.types, function(data, idx) {
      if(_.isEqual(data.value, String(_this.tenant.divisible))) {
        index = idx;
      }
    });
    _this.tenant.divisible = _this.types[index].value;
  };
  init();
```

but there is an error :

> undefined is not an object (evaluating 'a.types[t].value')

When i comment the line : `_this.tenant.divisible = _this.types[index].value;` all test build successful. I'm not be able to test this line correctly.

This is my test :

```
describe('Controller: TenantEditCtrl', function () {
  beforeEach(module('app'));

  var ctrl;
  var state;

  beforeEach(inject(function ($state, $controller, $rootScope) {
    state = $state.get('app.tenant_edit');
    //TODO: test with proper data
    ctrl = $controller('TenantEditCtrl', {
      $scope: $rootScope.$new(),
      tenant: {
        data: {}
      }
    });
  }));

  it('should initialize state properly', function () {
    expect(state.url).toEqual('/tenants/edit/:id');
  });

  it('should resolve data', function () {
    expect(ctrl.tenant).not.toBeNull();
  });

})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`index` in expression `_this.tenant.divisible = _this.types[index].value;` is `undefined` because in tests `tenant.data` is set to empty object and doesn't have `divisible` property. When you iterate over `types` you compare `type.value` to `"undefined"` and can't find correct type. One way to fix this is to instantiate controller with correct tenant data:

```
  beforeEach(inject(function ($state, $controller, $rootScope) {
    state = $state.get('app.tenant_edit');
    ctrl = $controller('TenantEditCtrl', {
      $scope: $rootScope.$new(),
      tenant: {
        data: {
          // set divisible
          divisible: true
        }
      }
    });
  }));
```